# SSLVerifyClient ignore expiration date

Tags: apache, ssl, client

I have a web service and is configured to verify client certificates

```
SSLCACertificateFile /xxxx/rootca-cert.pem

<Location /manage/ccc>
  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLVerifyDepth 1
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Location>
```

My clients are all running with certificates signed by this `rootca-cert.pem`.

My problem is that the rootca file is about to be expired soon, and it is not easy for me to update the certificates at the client side. Is it possible to configure the apache so that it continues verifying the client certs but ignore the fact that both rootca and client certs are expired ?

Answer (score 3):

Apache mod_ssl does not allow you to ignore expired certificates, even if using "optional_no_ca". The only fix is to patch mod_ssl code or to set your server's time back in time.